# unhandled exception when add control runtime

Tags: vb.net

i try add Textbox in panel at runtime but i get error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Judge.exe
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

and my code is:

```
Dim nl As New TextBox
AddHandler nl.LostFocus, AddressOf lost_focus
nl.Focus()
Panel1.Container.Add(nl)
```

and i use sub to add it and i call it from other form
and its UserControl.

thanks.

Comment: As always, at which line does the exception occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Panel1.Container` is probably wrong. Try `Panel1.Controls.Add(nl)`.

Comment: Thanks i forgot that :)